# What should be noticed when setting SS segment in the begining of OS development?

Tags: assembly, x86

Should I turn off interrupt?

How many situation I should concern?

Is there any documents for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to change `(E)SP` together with `SS` (and usually you have to), then if interrupts are enabled, it must be done using either a single `LSS (E)SP, ...` instruction or two instructions `MOV SS, ...`+`MOV (E)SP, ...` (in exactly this order). If you first change `(E)SP` and then `SS`, or if you first change `SS`, then execute some other instructions and only then change `(E)SP`, you must do all that with disabled interrupts (e.g. with `CLI`) because otherwise you'll have a window within which the pair `SS:(E)SP` will be incorrect/inconsistent and any interrupt that occurs at that time will likely corrupt memory.

You can read about all this in [intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx#manuals) CPU manuals.

Comment: So is setting SS and SP be the only case that I should use cli?

Comment: I said it already: if you use `MOV SS, ...` and then immediately `MOV (E)SP, ...`, you don't need to disable interrupts. Or if you use `LSS (E)SP, ...`, you don't need to disable interrupts.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. What I ask is 'Is any other usage of cli totally different with SS ?'. For example (I'm not sure): implementing mutax , scheduling,...etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking now. Be specific.

Comment: I am trying to understand all the case of using cli, not just about the stack operations. If I can understand all the situations that should use cli, I can prevent from unpredictable situation to happen.

Comment: That deserves a separate question. But I think it's a wrong approach as there can be many "unpredictable" situations and whether or not one should use `cli` or something else will depend completely on the problem at hand.